# laravel login auth with related table

Tags: laravel, authentication

I have 2 tables with the names Users and User_info

I want to do the login auth with email and mobile

The email is stored in Table Users and the mobile is in Table User_info

Can someone guide me?

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this

```
 $credential = filter_var($request->login, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? 'email' : 'phone';
        $login = $request->login;
        if($credential == 'email'){
             User::where('email',$login)->first();
            //Some logic
        }else{
             User::whereHas('user_info',function($q) use ($login){
                       $q->where('mobile',$login);
                   })->first();
            //do some logic
        }
```

Comment: Will I put it in method `protected function credentials(Request $request)`?

Comment: Yes, you can put that in login function.

Answer (score 0):

First search in users table for the input value. If the result is zero then search in user_info table.

Example :

```
if(count($user = \App\User::where('email',$request->email)->first()) > 0)
\\Login Logics like Auth::LoginUsingId($user->id)
elseif(count($user = \App\UserInfo::where('phone_number',$request->phone_number)->first()) > 0))
\\Login Logics like Auth::LoginUsingId($user->id)
```